# JPA error code 1054 en un intento de hacer cascada

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo personas y usuarios, cada persona puede tener muchos usuarios, un OneToMany en toda regla, pero no consigo que funcione, el codigo es este:

Persona:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByIdPersona", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.idPersona = :idPersona")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByNombre", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.nombre = :nombre")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByApellidoMaterno", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.apellidoMaterno = :apellidoMaterno")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByApellidoPaterno", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.apellidoPaterno = :apellidoPaterno")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByTelefono", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.telefono = :telefono")})
public class Persona implements Serializable {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ej3javaPU");
    private static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    private static EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idPersona")
    private Integer idPersona;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "apellido_materno")
    private String apellidoMaterno;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "apellido_paterno")
    private String apellidoPaterno;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "telefono")
    private String telefono;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="persona",  orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Usuarios> listUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();


public Persona() {
}

public Persona(Integer idPersona) {
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
}

public Persona(Integer idPersona, String nombre, String apellidoPaterno,String apellidoMaterno, String email, String telefono) {
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
    this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
    this.email = email;
    this.telefono = telefono;
}
public void addUser(Usuarios usuario) {
    listUsuarios.add(usuario);
    usuario.setPersona(this);
}
public static void mostrarTodos(){
    List<Persona> personas = em.createNamedQuery("Persona.findAll").getResultList();
    for(Persona p : personas){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
public static void insertar(){

    tx.begin();
    Persona persona1 = new Persona(null, "Juan", "Pedro", null, "platano@gmail.com","235345435");
    Usuarios usuario = new Usuarios();
    usuario.setNombre("juancho");
    usuario.setPassword("platano");
    persona1.addUser(usuario);
    em.persist(persona1);
    tx.commit();
}
```

Usuario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuarios.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuarios u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuarios.findByIdUsuario", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE u.idUsuario = :idUsuario")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuarios.findByIdPersona", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE u.idPersona = :idPersona")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuarios.findByNombre", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE u.nombre = :nombre")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuarios.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE u.password = :password")})
public class Usuarios implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idUsuario")
    private Integer idUsuario;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idPersona")
    private int idPersona;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Persona persona;

public Usuarios() {
}

public Usuarios(Integer idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public Usuarios(Integer idUsuario, int idPersona, String nombre, String password) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getIdUsuario() {
    return idUsuario;
}
public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
    this.persona = persona;

}
```

El error que me sale es:

> Internal Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'PERSONA_idPersona' in 'field list' Error Code: 1054 Call:
>   INSERT INTO usuarios (idPersona, nombre, password, PERSONA_idPersona)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)   bind => [4 parameters bound] Query:
>   InsertObjectQuery(Usuarios{idUsuario=null, idPersona=0,
>   nombre=juancho, password=platano, persona=Persona{idPersona=211,
>   nombre=Juan, apellidoMaterno=null, apellidoPaterno=Pedro,
>   email=platano@gmail.com, telefono=235345435, Usuarios=211}})

No entiendo eso de PERSONA_idPersona, en que momento digo yo que utilice esa columna inexistente?

PD: Lo que o ejecuto en el main es solamente insertar();, y los setters y getters que no hay estan, solo he copiado el código "importante"

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar la parte de código donde definas los atributos de las clases `Persona` y `Usuarios`? Para ver como tienes definidas las anotaciones `@Column` y demás. Si estás usando spring con hibernate, puedes pegar también lo que tengas en las propiedades de tipo: spring.jpa.hibernate.naming  ?

Comment: ya está, codigo actualizado

Comment: Si tienes campos definidos como optioinl= false , porque no incluyes esos datos en la creacion?

Comment: basicamente porque la id del usuario es autoincremental, y la idpersona tiene que salir de la cascada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la clase Usuario adicional a la etiqueta @ManyToOne debe agregar @JoinColumn que identifica a la clave foránea en la Tabla Usuario:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColunn[name="ID_PERSONA")
private Persona persona;
```

En el código ID_PERSONA es la clave foránea en la tabla USUARIO . La tabla PERSONA debe tener como clave primaria ID_PERSONA. En el supuesto que la tabla PERSONA tiene una clave primaria ID y en la Tabla USUARIO se llama ID_PERSONA, entonces  al JoinColumn deberás agregar referenceColumnName="ID". En resumen, con la etiqueta @JoinColumn tienesb que indicar cuales son los campos que están relacionados.

**EDICION:** Como ya estás definiendo la clase Persona persona asociada al "idPersona", entonces, **debes eliminar la definición de campo idPersona y todos sus métodos y referencias a éste**. En adelante debes usar **persona**.

```
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idPersona")
    private int idPersona;
```

El NamedQuery

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Usuarios.findByIdPersona", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE u.idPersona = :idPersona")
```

debes cambiarlo por:

```
, @NamedQuery(name = "Usuarios.findByIdPersona", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuarios u WHERE u.persona.idPersona = :idPersona")
```

Comment: `Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [usuarios.idPersona].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[persona]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(ej3java.Usuarios --> [DatabaseTable(usuarios)])`

ahora me sale eso, poniendo el name=idPersona

Comment: En la Entidad Usuario debes quitar la definicion de IdPersona porque ya la tienes en el join